# trouble while using mysql and count request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I met some trouble while using mysql, In fact I have a table formated like that:

```
n_doss   etat     date       etc...
-----------------------------------
145        N      20/10
145        EC     15/10
146        N      25/10
```

What I would like to do is for each `etat` to count how much folder I have (folders are identified by `n_doss`).

the trouble is that the last `etat` that is important is the most recent for each file.

So I have to count for each `etat` how much file I have, but I can not count each `etat` for each `n_doss` but just the most recent.

I've tried almost everything but I can not succeed in this query.

I've tried:

```
SELECT  `etat` , `n_doss`, COUNT(  'etat' ) 
FROM  `commentaire` WHERE  
GROUP BY  `etat`
```

This does not work with what I try to do.

I also tried

```
SELECT `etat` , `n_doss`, COUNT(  'etat' ) 
FROM  `commentaire`   
GROUP BY  `n_doss`
HAVING max(date) with
```

with acualy no success.
Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a primary key in your table?

Comment: yes the id is primary key (it is auto_increment), but I have also Indexes

Comment: on the sample records given above, what would be your desired output?

Comment: the count of each `etat` but each file can have many records, I just need for each file the last `etat` identified by the `date`

Comment: `COUNT('etat')` is wrong. The single quotes denote a character literal, not a column name. Your expression equivalent to `count(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, c.totalCOunt
FROM    commentaire a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT etat, MAX(date) maxDate
            FROM commentaire
            GROUP BY etat
        ) b ON a.etat = b.etat AND
                a.date = b.maxDate
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT etat, COUNT(*) totalCOunt
            FROM commentaire
            GROUP BY etat
        ) c ON a.etat = c.etat
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1109bd/4)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Actualy I met some trouble with the number of files

Comment: Actualy this request counts also the number of file if there is a date before In your example it counts 3 file as total but it should count only 2 because they are the same file just that the `etat` is different I will try to correct this. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  c.*, cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  etat, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    commentaire
        GROUP BY
                etat
        ) cd
JOIN    commentaire c
ON      c.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    commentaire ci
        WHERE   ci.etat = cd.etat
        ORDER BY
                date DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `(etat, date, id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Actualy this code does not return me how much I have `n_doss` per `etat`

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT  `etat` , COUNT(  'n_doss' ) 
FROM  `commentaire`  
GROUP BY  `etat`
```

Comment: Just cut WHERE, if you don't have any conditions